# Binding Command MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, view

I have two different views and they are:

```
GreeView 
DetailView
```

Each has its own `ViewModel` and they are:

```
GreeViewModel
DetailViewModel
```

Is it possible to call Commands that resides in `DetailViewModel` from `GreeView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921159%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx